# ¿Es correcto el uso de "también" en "pero también jamás fui tan feliz"?

Tags: gramática, adverbios, letras-de-canciones

Reciéntemente escuché una [canción](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=868507) de Ricardo Arjona, en la cual encontré una frase que me dejó dudas sobre su validez:

> He venido a parar con la mujer que no soñé jamás
>
> pero también jamás... fui tan feliz...

La parte de "también jamás..." me suena mal. Al estar enlazando dos frases con sentido negativo, ¿no debería utilzarse *tampoco* en lugar de *también*?

Comment: Sí,  sí que es válido.  Desconozco la explicación gramatical, pero en España sí se dice así

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que sí tiene sentido: la mujer con la que él ha *venido a parar* es lo contrario a la mujer que marcan los cánones del momento (*Me gusta porque es autentica y vive sin recetas / de esas que tratan de vestir al amor de etiqueta*, dice un poco antes). Por ello dice que *He venido a parar con la mujer que no soñé jamás* en el sentido de que una persona así nunca estuvo entre sus cánones.

Sin embargo, a él le gusta y le hace inmensamente feliz. Por tanto, para decirlo contrapone el sentimiento negativo con el positivo usando un *también*:

> Me ha pasado X pero también Y

Y es como si dijera:

> Pese a venir a parar con la mujer que no soñé jamás / soy tan feliz...

Si por el contrario usara *tampoco* daría a entender que el segundo sentimiento es también negativo, cuando *jamás fui tan feliz* es claramente positivo, pues define el momento actual de felicidad máxima.

Comment: Muy buena explicación. Tiene mucho sentido.